# Moving objects as a list

Tags: python, list, object

So in the below code I am trying to give a menu of instructions. What I am having problems with is the 'N' command section that calls the MakeTurtle() function. I am trying to add all turtles to a list (children []) so when I iterate through the list it makes all the turtles move at the same time. The problem is I can only get one turtle to move (the first one I create). Previously I was able to get them all to move, but it would stop working if I made a new one. Can anyone help?

```
home = makeWorld()
children = []


def MakeTurtle():
  newborn = makeTurtle(home)
  children.append(newborn)
  return newborn


def RoamingTurtles():
  command = raw_input("---> ")
  if command == 'N':
    MakeTurtle() 
    RoamingTurtles() 
  if command == 'R':
    for i in children:
      i.turn(90)
      RoamingTurtles()
  if command == 'L':
    for i in children:
      i.turn(-90)
      RoamingTurtles()
  if command == 'M':
    for i in children:
      i.forward()
      RoamingTurtles()
  if command == 'Q':  
     print 'End'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue appears to be that you're not waiting until the loop over all children completes before recalling the `RoamingTurtle` function.  This is why only one of your turtles updates.  For example, you have:

```
for i in children:
  i.forward()
  RoamingTurtles()
```

but instead, you want:

```
for i in children:
  i.forward()
RoamingTurtles()
```

Comment: I think this is the right diagnosis of the problem, but I would suggest a `while True` loop as an alternative to the recursion.

Comment: Definitely, I agree with @Blckknght,  a `while` loop is a much better option in this situation.

Comment: If I could kiss you I would. And I'm hairy so it wouldn't be nice! But thank you.

Comment: I ticked the box I assume that means you answered my question.